# How to lookup ejb on JBoss AS 7.x

Tags: ejb, jndi, lookup, jboss7.x

I try ejb lookup for jndi name. 
That ejb is same jboss server then is success. But ejb is other jboss server then is failed.
My source code:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put("java.naming.provider.url","jnp://192.168.100.10:8484");
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial",
                "org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory");
env.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
                "org.jboss.as.naming.interfaces.java");
env.put("java.naming.security.principal", "Admin");
env.put("java.naming.security.credentials",
            "password");
Context context = new InitialContext(env);
IMyLogic infoLogic = (IMyLogic) context.lookUp("java:global/MyApplication/MyModule/MyLogic!org.test.interfaces.IMyLogic");
```

IMyLogic ejb 192.168.100.10 jboss as 7.1 deployed.
I try lookup 192.168.100.15 jboss as 7.1.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this guide to make remote invocations to an EJB from a standalone client:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

Or if you are in another JBoss instance, then use the accompanying article:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance

Comment: Thanks, but I don't lookup ejb another jboss server.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I can lookup ejb from another server. But How to standalone.xml configurations dynamically for code. help me.